# Xamarin.Forms - App does not open

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio 2015 on a Windows 10 machine. When I create a Xamarin.Forms(Android/iOS) cross-platform project and start the AVD, the emulator works, but the application does not open. I don't receive errors in Visual Studio.

[image: Logcat Error]

It's just a test:

```
        public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new ContentPage
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = {
                     new Label {
                         HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                         Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                     }
                 }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual code?

Comment: It's a vs template application.

Comment: Did you try to deploy your app on a real device? Sometimes I have the same problem but with a real device it's working

Comment: Try to use the higher api level device. And can you get the error message of vs2015 not logcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of effort i update my android sdk tools and all starts work again, thx everyone. Version 25.2.3.